# Is this sentence correct? "User listed already having an attorney."

Tags: possessives

Settle an argument in my office:

Is this a valid sentence?

> " The other 6 were rejected because user listed already having an attorney."

The disagreement is that it should say

> "The other 6 were rejected because user is listed as already having an attorney."

Comment: Both are fine-ish. They just have different meanings. Did user make a list or was user put on a list?

Comment: @keepthesemind could you please clarify the different meaning between the two sentences? Thanks!

Comment: apologies @keepthesemind I didn't see your edit before I posted! 
The user listed themselves as already having an attorney. I'm not sure which one that would be.

Comment: *Because* needs a finite verb, which is missing in the first instance.

Comment: @TeddJohnson Well, i) did user provide a list about herself that included the item 'with attorney' or ii) did user (or somebody else) put her on a list of users that have an attorney?

Comment: @deadrat How is _listed_ not a finite verb, if it is _user_ who is doing the _listing_?

Comment: @keepthesemind the first one.

Comment: @TeddJohnson Then I think the first sentence is better, although perhaps an alternative to _listed_ (like _indicated_) would be better. (Unless deadrat has a point.)

Comment: @Keepthesemind Because as the second sentence shows, *listed* is to be applied to *user*. For that to work in the first sentence, there would have to be a reflexive pronoun: *because* [the] *user listed **himself** as already having an attorney*.

Comment: @deadrat You can't derive the meaning of one sentence from the meaning of the other. That's why it is a question. Also, you _can_ list "I have an attorney" among other stuff. Although _indicate_ would be better.

Comment: @Keepthesemind The derivation isn't mine. The OP is positing the sentences are equivalent; he's just unsure which is "proper".

Comment: If you're using the first sentence, then _listed_ must have the meaning of _included on a list_, _registered_. So, it requires that it is _user_ who is doing the _listing_ or _registering_.

Comment: @deadrat Fair point. Which brings me back to my first comment: The sentences have different meanings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes (to the title question), the sentence

> User listed already having an attorney.

is valid. *However* it can only mean

> [The] User included on a list already having an attorney.

or

> [The] User placed **herself** in the category 'already having an attorney'.

See http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/list.

That implies that the two alternatives (in the body of the question) have different meanings, because the second alternative means

> The other 6 were rejected because [the] user is listed [**by us, the company etc.**] as already having an attorney.